# Test if an object is a TinyMCE editor

Tags: tinymce

How to test if an Object is a TinyMCE editor instance?

Comment: The only way I can think of doing it is looping through all _tinymce.editors_ and comparing the object to them. It does seem like there should be a better way though.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what kind of object you want to check for and the time of this check looping through `tinymce.editors` may not be suffcient. In case you want to check if an object is a tinymce editor object and there is no initialized tinymce editor then `tinymce.editors` will be an empty array, even though your object may be a valid tinymce editor object (without an active editor!).

If you got an `object` you can test if this object has the following properties. This should be sufficient:

```
if(object.editorCommands && object.editorId && object.execCommands && object.plugins) return true;
```

If this does not suit your use case you will need to provide more information.

Comment: This works too I suppose, but if you are extremely unlucky there could still be a false positive.